# Cannot clone from gcloud to git: "Could not find gcloud's git credential helper."

Tags: linux, git, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've got a git repository in Google's Cloud Platform.  I'm trying to clone it into a local git report like this:

```
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
gcloud source repos clone myrepository --project=myprojectid
```

It's giving me this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Could not find gcloud's git credential helper. Please make sure the Cloud SDK bi
n folder is in PATH.
```

I've verified that gcloud is in $PATH:

```
> which gcloud
/usr/bin/gcloud
```

This is a new GCE instance of SUSE.  Works on mac but not on this SUSE server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud SDK's **bin folder** needs to be in `$PATH`, not just `gcloud`.

`/usr/bin/gcloud` is likely either a symlink or a wrapper script that points to a full, `google-cloud-sdk` installation directory. You need to add `google-cloud-sdk/bin` to your path, since that's where the credential helper is.

(This is due to a limitation in the git-credential-helper model.

Comment: Quick response.  Ok, I've found /usr/bin/gcloud points here:

:/usr/bin> cat gcloud
#!/bin/sh
python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py "$@"

I've tried adding it to $PATH:
echo $PATH
/home/michael_ryerse/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
googlecloudsdk:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlecloudsdk/gcloud

Still throwing the same error though.

Comment: That's not a proper bin folder–the SUSE package isn't published by google, so it might be a little different. You need to find the `git-credential-gcloud.sh` file, and make sure *that* is on your $PATH. It may be easiest to just install another copy of the Cloud SDK.

Comment: I switched from the suse to the debian instance of GCE.  Had to install git but once it was installed it was able to clone from cloud sdk without a problem.